# "Who cares here" meaning

Tags: meaning

What does means "who cares here?" and to whom pronoun "you" refers in the following context?

> So I went. It was frightening. I played. I thought, who cares here? You played Bach prelude and fugue, Chopin study, one of the Tchaikovsky Seasons and a classical sonata. For the final you had to play Tchaikovsky 1 and another concerto - I did Brahms 1 - and you had to do them back-to-back.

I found the phrase in this article: http://www.theartsdesk.com/classical-music/qa-special-pianist-barry-douglas

Comment: "you" means "one", here, one (of the contestants).  "to care" means "to have a concern for someone or something".   Perhaps the speaker is saying that the contest is grueling, and is wondering if the judges might have no concern for the well-being of the contestants. It is not perfectly clear.

Comment: Note that this passage is written in an odd condensed style, omitting articles which would normally be required,  before "Bach prelude and fugue" and "Chopin study"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rare example of second-person narration.  The narrator is talking to himself in reported speech ("I thought,....").